# Host local web page from Android app

Tags: android, ip, host

I've just started using an app called "wifi file transfer". The way it works is that you run the app on your phone, the phone hosts a webpage and you can access it from any computer on that network with the phones ip address and the port number.

I just want to know how that works, any body know of any tutorials or anywhere I can get started?

EDIT:
I'm looking for java code to see how this works, not just another app.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in order to host a web page you will be needing Apache or IIS servers.

Comment: It is possible... have you tried AirDroid app.. It is the same thing

Comment: It is possible, I just told you what the app does. Sorry if I didn't make my self clear, I wanted some java code to see how it works :)

Comment: AirDroid sure does look a lot better though, will be swiching to that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give a try to [NanoHTTPD](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/). It is small, lightweight and easily configurable.

Comment: This is great, got the example up and running in minutes. Exactly what I'm after, thanks a lot :)